# jq to parse aws ec2 instance tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jq

I need to convert this output

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]' | jq -s 'from_entries | del(..|.["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]?)'

{
  "Key": "ssh_user",
  "Value": "abc"
}
{
  "Key": "ssh_port",
  "Value": "2200"
}
{
  "Key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName",
  "Value": "ASG-Api"
}
{
  "Key": "Name",
  "Value": "SV-V3-API"
}
```

into this one using jq:

```
{
 "ssh_user":"abc",
 "ssh_port":"2200",
 "Name":"SV-V3-API"
}
```

Note that I need to delete this key: ***aws:autoscaling:groupName***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jq 1.5:

```
$ jq -cs 'from_entries | del(.["aws:autoscaling:groupName"])'
```

With jq 1.3 or 1.4:

```
$ jq -M -c -s 'reduce .[] as $x
   ([]; . + [{"key" : $x.Key, "value": $x.Value}])
 | from_entries
 | del(.["aws:autoscaling:groupName"])'
```

On Windows, you'll need to modify the quoting, or put the jq commands into a file.

Comment: Not works: $ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]' | jq -c -s 'from_entries | del(.["aws:autoscaling:groupName"])'     jq: error: Cannot use null as object key

Comment: @user3742266 What is the purpose of piping several jq commands together?

Comment: For jq 1.4, you could use sed to downcase Key and Value, e.g. `$ sed -e 's/Key/key/' -e 's/Value/value/' 881.json | /usr/local/bin/jq -M -c -s 'from_entries | del(.["aws:autoscaling:groupName"])' `    
{"ssh_key":"id_rsa.pem","ansible":"v3p","v3_api_prod":"True","ssh_user":"abc","ssh_port":"2200","Name":"SV-V3-API","supervisor":"9009"}`

Comment: @peak, your solution works with jq 1.3 too. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3742266 Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can thank this answerer by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer. This helps other users to know this question has been resolved. You will also gain a small amount of reputation for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think @peak's comment about `sed` is important enough to get a separate answer.

`jq` version 1.4 and lower cannot work with Amazon's key/value pairs natively using `from_entries` because Amazon upper-cases keys while `jq` expects lower-case keys. The `jq` team [addressed this](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/592) with version 1.5.

To get the your EC2 instances' tags as `key: value` pairs, instead of `{key, value}` entries, use:

```
aws ... | \
  sed -e 's/"Key":/"key":/g' -e 's/"Value":/"value":/g' | \
  jq '.Reservations[]|.Instances[]|.Tags|from_entries'
```

Comment: You don't even need sed to remap them, just remap them prior to conversion. `[.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]|{key:.Key,value:.Value}]|from_entries`